# Ubuntu 17.10 Unable to Lock Screen

Tags: gnome, 17.10, lock-screen, dbus, gnome-settings-daemon

No matter how I try to lock my screen (Super + L, Menu Item, or Time Out) the screen tries to lock, but freezes for a second, and resumes my running gnome session as it was. If I try again after that, my session freezes and has to be restarted.

If my computer is left at the regular login screen with no user signed in, It will respect power settings, and turn the screen off after 10 minutes.

The following is a dump of my Syslog at the time of crash.

```
 gnome-shell[10234]: Extension "ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com" had error: TypeError: dockManager is null
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
 gnome-shell[10234]: The actor 'ShellGenericContainer' is currently being destroyed, and cannot be added as a child of another actor.
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed TopIcons@phocean.net
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
 gnome-shell[10234]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55b266c13730' has no handler with id '10398'
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 gnome-shell[10234]: message repeated 2 times: [ g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed]
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed arc-menu@linxgem33.com
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
 gnome-software[10414]: no app for changed remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com
 gnome-shell[10234]: WARNING: addSignalMethods is replacing existing [0x55b2699452b0 Gjs_ShowAppsIcon.dash-item-container] connect method
 gnome-shell[10234]: WARNING: addSignalMethods is replacing existing [0x55b2699452b0 Gjs_ShowAppsIcon.dash-item-container] disconnect method
 gnome-shell[10234]: WARNING: addSignalMethods is replacing existing [0x55b2699452b0 Gjs_ShowAppsIcon.dash-item-container] emit method
 gnome-shell[10234]: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock' does not contain a key named 'customize-alphas'
 kernel: [38115.855449] traps: gnome-shell[10234] trap int3 ip:7fc0a6738961 sp:7ffe8d7e77b0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5400.1[7fc0a66e8000+111000]
 gnome-session[10148]: gnome-session-binary[10148]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
 gnome-session-binary[10148]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
 gsd-media-keys[10337]: Couldn't lock screen: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc MX279 (DFP-1): connected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc MX279 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc MX279 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal DisplayPort
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: disconnected
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: Internal TMDS
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10136]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js 315]: reference to undefined property "MetaStage"
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js 221]: reference to undefined property "MetaWindowGroup"
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/osdMonitorLabeler.js 59]: reference to undefined property "MetaDBusDisplayConfigSkeleton"
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js 540]: reference to undefined property "isSpecialProperty"
 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12138]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/slider.js 38]: reference to undefined property "CallyActor"
 dbus[1127]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service'
 systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
 dbus[1127]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
 systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [/home/USERNAME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js 34]: reference to undefined property Symbol.toPrimitive
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [/home/USERNAME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com/extension.js 45]: reference to undefined property "text"
 gnome-shell[12138]: loading user theme: /usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'SignalManager' on the module 'convenience'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'SoundDeviceChooserBase' on the module 'base'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'SETTINGS_SCHEMA' on the module 'prefs'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [/home/USERNAME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net/convenience.js 193]: reference to undefined property Symbol.toPrimitive
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'SHOW_INPUT_SLIDER' on the module 'prefs'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'DBusMenu' on the module 'interfaces'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'WORKAROUND_RELOAD_TYPE_REGISTER' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'StatusNotifierWatcher' on the module 'statusNotifierWatcher'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'StatusNotifierWatcher' on the module 'interfaces'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'traverseBusNames' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1361]: unreachable code after return statement
 gnome-shell[12138]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/extension.js 44]: assignment to undeclared variable runningExtensions
 gnome-shell[12138]: length values must specify a unit
 gnome-shell[12138]: message repeated 3 times: [ length values must specify a unit]
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'Logger' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Failed to acquire org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'introspectBusObject' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 bluetoothd[1110]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'dbusNodeImplementsInterfaces' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
 gnome-shell[12138]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore was not provided by any .service files
 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12138]: Window manager warning: "XF86RFKill" is not a valid accelerator
 gnome-shell[12138]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Using Brute-force mode for StatusNotifierItem :1.255/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
 gnome-shell[12138]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.255/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
 gnome-shell[12138]: Some code accessed the property 'AppIndicator' on the module 'appIndicator'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
<...snip>
```

Of particular interest is the line: `gsd-media-keys[10337]: Couldn't lock screen: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying` but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Installed and active Extensions: Arc Menu, Removable Drive Menu, Remove Dropdown Arrows, Topicons Plus, UserThemes.

Hardware: AMD Ryzen 1700X, 16gb Ram, NVidia GTX 1080.
Software: Ubuntu 17.10, Kernel 4.13.0-16-generic, Gnome.

Please and thanks! Let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986182/ubuntu-17-10-screen-lock-not-working-and-grey not the same problem but might help somebody else: need to use command line to enable the GUI for locking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the package *gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock* (which also removed the *ubuntu-desktop* package...) and I think this is working now. Submitted a bug-report.

Comment: Would you please share the bug-report link?