# Ubuntu 17.04 no longer asking for password when coming out of sleep mode

Tags: suspend, password, 17.04

For some reason, when I open my laptop and it wakes up, it no longer asks me for my user password (it used to). How do I troubleshoot this and enable password request upon wake?

Comment: Anything in syslog or dmesg around the time of the wakeup ?  Can you paste it here or link it to pastebin ?

Comment: This happens intermittently for me on 16.04. Is it still always happening for you or just sometimes?

Comment: You mention closing and opening lid for suspend/resume actions. What happens when you select **Suspend** from the menu and use power button to resume?

Comment: Same behavior. It wakes up and I’m back at my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1 is Screensaver installed?

The password when resuming from suspend is based on lock screen screen and lock screen is based upon screen saver. To check screen saver use `apt list --installed | grep saver`:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gnome-screensaver/xenial,now 3.6.1-7ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
```

If you don't see a screen saver above then use:

```
sudo apt install gnome-screensaver
```

## Step 2 is lock screen enabled?

Lock screen needs to be enabled:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
false
```

If result is `true` then use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: Yep, `gnome-screensaver` is installed.

Comment: @ffxsam Does manual lock screen work and ask for password?

Comment: Aha! Now we're onto something. Super+L does not lock the system as it should. And that key shortcut is defined properly.

Comment: Try `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen`

Comment: I just noticed I have this same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986182/ubuntu-17-10-screen-lock-not-working-and-grey

Comment: The value returned is `true` for the gsettings

Comment: I updated the answer with the solution

Comment: That fixed it!! Thank you! I have no idea how that happened.. I certainly didn't set it.

Comment: Glad it works. Thanks for pointing out the similar problem, I copied a portion of the answer over there for them.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
```

if it comes back with 'false' set this to 'true' with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
```

You can also do this with a GUI, using `dconf-editor` - navigate to 'org->gnome->desktop->screensaver->ubuntu-lock-on-suspend'

Comment: The result is `true`. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

It's so because Automatic Suspend may be off.

Turning it on will solve the problem. Here is how:

1. Go to Settings > Power.

[image]

2. Click 'Automatic Suspend' option.

[image]

3. Turn "When Idle" option on.

[image]

Done.
Let me know if this solves your problem or not.

Comment: Nope, it was not off. And it's set to "when on battery", delay of 15 mins. There is no "when idle" option. (I'm on Ubuntu 17.10)

Comment: I think my installation must've gotten corrupted somehow.

Comment: GNOME or Unity?

Comment: GNOME. ........

Answer (score 0):

Check the suspend logs at /var/log/pm-suspend.log

```
sudo nano /var/log/pm-suspend.log
```

**Possible Solution 1:**

Edit the file '/etc/systemd/logind.conf'

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Removed the # comment from the beginning of the line  'HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore' and changed the value to be:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

Restart the systemd daemon with this command:

```
sudo restart systemd-logind
```

or, from 15.04 onwards:

```
sudo service systemd-logind restart
```

Comment: No such luck. And there is no `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`. It's not necessarily closing the lid that's the issue. Suspend in general doesn't require a password when waking up.