# Ubuntu 20.04 not asking password when coming out of sleep

Tags: suspend, password, lock-screen, screensaver, gnome-screensaver

Ubuntu doesn't ask for my password when I'm getting out of sleep when closing my laptop and reopening it. 
I've followed everything listed here : [Ubuntu 17.04 no longer asking for password when coming out of sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992418/ubuntu-17-04-no-longer-asking-for-password-when-coming-out-of-sleep-mode) but it keeps not asking my password. 
Moreover, the command Super + L doesn't lock the screen either. You can find below screens of my settings ( in french, sorry, but it shouldn't be difficult to understand what it corresponds to. So the options for automatic lock of the screen and locking screen when in sleep mode are activated, and the delay for locking the scren is " when screen shuts" ) [image]

Moreover, you can see here that the command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
```

gives true, and

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

gives false.

[image]

It could be related to issues I had some time ago with i3 that wasn't asking either for a password when getting into sleep mode. I remember that I tried different manips but can't remember the details. I've already removed i3 totally.

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution here [Ubuntu 18.04 refuses to use lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073339/ubuntu-18-04-refuses-to-use-lock-screen)

I just needed to add the following command on the startup applications :

```
gnome-screensaver &
```

Don't know what was the issue exactly, but happy to see that it finally works. I've spent so many hours on this

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue in 20.04. When I do ```gnome-screensaver-command -l```, it doesn't do anything but if I then run ```gnome-screensaver &``` I get ```Gtk-Message: 09:16:12.329: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module" Gtk-Message: 09:16:12.330: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module" Gtk-Message: 09:16:12.331: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"  ```. Now for next few tries screen is locked after suspend, but goes back to its original not-locked-after-suspend self. Any tips?