# Screen lock not working (Window+L) not working

Tags: password, lock-screen, lock

I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS. When I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 18.xx/19.xx(sorry i don't remember) to Ubuntu 20.04, my screen lock suddenly stopped working.

Earlier when I press Windows(Super) + L, my Ubuntu screen locks and and require password to open but after upgrading it stopped working. And I even tried to lock from right corner from setting option to Lock, that is also not working.

I tried Super+Alt+L, this is also not working. If I do nothing for 15 min than laptop suspand but it does not ask for password when open. I saw my setting and everything was normal. See this [picture](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ppARcs-Jv10TEOuYzohubo7sRPEXjdbD?usp=sharing)

I looked on internet and tried every solution but It did not solve my problem. I tried these solution:
[link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831490/ubuntu-16-04-screen-lock-suddenly-not-working)
[Link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992418/ubuntu-17-04-no-longer-asking-for-password-when-coming-out-of-sleep-mode/1000243#1000243)
[Link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986182/ubuntu-17-10-screen-lock-not-working-and-grey)
[Link4](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-lockscreen-not-working/)
update: I am using lightdm display manager so when in my terminal when I type `dm-tool lock` ,it lock the screen and require password to open.
I changed my display manager to gdm3 but that also didn't help.
Please help.
Thank You

Comment: I am facing this problem for more than 10+ months. I was at home so I did not care about lock but Now I go to outside so I asked the solution as this is a problem if not locked outside. @guiverc

Comment: Is the shortcut key properly defined in Settings - Keyboard?

Comment: @vanadium yes I checked and tried to change also but didnt work